# Separate prime numbers from array

Tags: java, primes

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args) {

        int [] arr = {2, 5, 9, 6, 7, 13, 24, 42, 8};
        int [] arr1 = new int[4];
        int [] arr2 = new int[arr.length - arr1.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 2; j <= arr[i]/2; j++) {
                if(arr[i] % j == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Number is not prime " + arr[i]);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Number is prime " + arr[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program should check an array of numbers and print if the given number is prime. There is something wrong, since the first 2 are not marked as prime. Then I don't know why 9 was taken as a prime number.

Comment: You are always breaking from the loop in the first iteration. You should only do that if you discover the number is not prime.

Comment: Because you're always breaking at the first iteration of the inner loop

Comment: Since *j* starts from 2 and the condition of the for is *j <= arr[i]/2* for 2 will lead to 2/2 = 1 ?>= 2 (false)...

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code.

1. **Why 2 is not taken as prime.**
   As explained by others, `j <= arr[i]/2` is the culprit. According to this condition, `j <= 1` and `j == 2`. So, the loop does not get executed.
2. **Why 9 is taken as prime.**
   For the the first time when `j == 2` and `arr[i] == 9`. As, `9%2 != 0`, the number is printed as prime.

   ```
   for(int j = 2; j <= arr[i]/2; j++){
       if(arr[i] % j == 0){
           System.out.println("Number is not prime " + arr[i]);
           break;
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("Number is prime " + arr[i]);
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

**Advice:**
 Instead of checking for `arr[i]/2`, you can use square root of number to check instead.

You can refer the following program if needed:

```
public class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String []args){

        int [] arr = {2,3,4,5,9,6,7,13,24,42,8,400,101};
        int [] arr1 = new int[4];
        int [] arr2 = new int[arr.length - arr1.length];
        boolean flag = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] == 2 || arr[i] == 3 )
            {
                System.out.println("Number is prime " + arr[i]);
                continue;
            }
            flag = true;
            for(int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt( arr[i] ); j++){
                if(arr[i] % j == 0){
                    System.out.println("Number is not prime " + arr[i]);
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( flag )
            {
                System.out.println("Number is prime " + arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Math.sqrt( arr[i] )` is calculated on every loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 2; j <= arr[i] / 2; j++) {
    if (arr[i] % j == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number is not prime " + arr[i]);
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Number is prime " + arr[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here you iterate **only once** and check if given number is dividable by 2 or not (i.e. this is equal to `arr[i] % 2 == 0`). To check if given number is prime or not, you have to check all numbers from **2** to **sqrt(val)**.

I recommend you to select this check into separate method.

```
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;

final IntPredicate isPrime = val -> {
    if (val < 2)
        return false;

    for (int i = 2, sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(val); i <= sqrt; i++)
        if (val % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
};
```

And your code looks much simpler:

```
int[] arr = { 2, 5, 9, 6, 7, 13, 2, 4, 42, 8 };

for (int val : arr) {
    if (isPrime.test(val))
        System.out.println("Number is prime " + val);
    else
        System.out.println("Number is not prime " + val);
}
```

Comment: please, specify necessary import. it is not compiling.
`import  java.util.function.IntPredicate;`

Answer (score -1):

you need to remove this condition in your second for loop
j <= arr[i]/2.

What you are looking for is j <= arr[i]

Comment: That's not the problem, you could even iterate until ``sqrt(arr[i])``